# How to remove class name and controller name from url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I'm developping a website using CI and today I'm facing a problem .
Here is my link .

```
http://example.com/subfolder/site/page/Snowman_Trek_24_Days
```

i want to change my link like

```
http://example.com/subfolder/Snowman_Trek_24_Days
```

i update my config file -

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

also i tested this -

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

In route.php file i used this code -

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'site';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['page/(:any)'] = "site/page/$1";
```

My htaccess code is :-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

After doing all this i am getting this error :-
Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.Can anybody help me .

Comment: The order of your routes are important... the `default_controller` should never be at the top as it would over-ride everything else... `default_controller` goes at the bottom.  Troubleshoot by commenting out routes and adding them back one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: in your `.htaccess` file put

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/# is this subfolder from URL we are speaking about?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ index.php?/subfolder/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now all your request should avoid subfolder segment in URL.
But also you have to design URLs in `APPPATH.'config/config.php'` file and in controller to have:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "site/page/$1";
```

So

```
http://example.com/subfolder/Snowman_Trek_24_Days
```

should be valid path.
Be aware of `(:any)` wildcard because it will reroute any other request not `site/page/$1` only and has to be at the end of `routes.php` file. Any other routes you want to execute, you have to put before that one explicitly. Example:

```
$route['login'] = 'auth/login';

$route['about'] = 'staticpage/about';
$route['contact'] = 'staticpage/contact';

$route['(:any)'] = "site/page/$1";
```

More of routing in [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).

Comment: Ok thank you let me try . i will update you soon sir.

Comment: " But also you have to design URLs in APPPATH.'config/config.php' file and in controller to have:" Sir i dont understand what should i do ?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http:domainname/subfolder/'; this is my base url .

Comment: Sorry, I meant routes, not config. For changing controller code I meant i.e if you are using `$this->uri->segment(4)` after code changes (if still works) now it would become `$this->uri->segment(2)` etc.